# how to remove the default spacing to the upper elements (big amount of div's)

Tags: html, css

I create a lot of div's (~200) using jquery the following way:

```
wrapper.append('<div class="clicker"></div>');
```

The clicker class looks like this

```
#wrapper .clicker{
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The JS part is working, however the elements are not aligned as expected.
WHere does the spacing come from? How to remove it?

It looks like this: (The small boxes with black border)
[image]

fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/xphvLrm9/

Comment: I think we're going to need some more code, could you possibly post an isolated example in jsFiddle?

Comment: sure - give me a second

Comment: Wild guess: there's `line-height` in `#wrapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to the `.clicker`

```
.clicker{
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qcrefr4d/

Comment: or you could change the `line-height: 3px;` on the `#warpper`!

Comment: float left worked for me in the fiddle - however line-height (in combination with float left) worked in the browser -thanks!

Comment: Cool, if this helped could mark my answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I'll need to wait one more minute - i ll mark it as correct soon

Answer (score 2):

Add `line-height:0px;` or `font-size:0px;` to `#wrapper`

`line-height:0px;` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xphvLrm9/1/)

`font-size:0px;` [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xphvLrm9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your `#wrapper` div's CSS, but I suspect that the `div` has an unintended `line-height` CSS attribute on itself.

This will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  insert();
});

function insert() {

  for ( var i = 0; 1000 > i; i++ ) {
 $('<div class="clicker"></div>').appendTo($('#wrapper'));
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper .clicker{
 width: 3px;
 height: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* line-height causes the vertical spaces.
set it to zero point, then the spaces will be gone. */
#wrapper {
  line-height:0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```